# Add Day in front of Date but Retain Date

Tags: calculated-column

One of my views groups by date, and I was asked to add the day to the front of it, such as "Wednesday October 26, 2016" or "Wednesday 10-26-2016".

I've tried using a concatenate and a bunch of text fields, but no dice. Here is where I stopped:

=TEXT(WEEKDAY([Due Date]),"dddd")&" "&MONTH([Due Date])&" "&DAY([Due Date])&", "&YEAR([Due Date])

Answer (score 2):

Below formula will work:

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DateColumn),"dddd")&" "&TEXT((DateColumn),"MMMM")&" "&DAY(DateColumn)&" ,"&YEAR(DateColumn)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers sort of work. The problem is their written month will always show January. Fix that by using `"&TEXT((Created),"MMMM")&"` at the month's position.

So the complete formula would be the following:

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(Created),"dddd")&" "&TEXT((Created),"MMMM")&" "&DAY(Created)&", "&YEAR(Created)
```

Comment: +1 for noticing that.

Comment: This groups everything in Dates, but yields "Unassigned" and does not actually show the date. Changing it to a "Single Line of Text" gives me the correct date, but I lose the ordered grouping by date, which was the problem at the jump.

Comment: @JoeFedorowicz do you mean the ordering of the grouping is required? Typically this would require the use of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date-/timestamp. If you want to get at least somewhere with the grouping, you could consider creating another calculated columns which only includes the month, the date, the weekday, etc. These columns do not necessarily need to be visible on the view, but they can still be used for the grouping.

Comment: Ok, and so that was my question. I didn't think it would be possible, but was hoping that SharePoint could prefix the date with the day, but keep the characteristics of the date.

Comment: @JoeFedorowicz The bad news are that using `WEEKDAY` seems to only work with `=TEXT` prefix, which again requires the use of `Single Line of Text`. However, I'd suggest you to have a look at this post: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16827.sharepoint-2010-group-by-view-with-order-by-on-datetime-field.aspx. It provides a workaround to sort the grouping by date. The grouping would be done for the original `[Due Date]` column, but on the view you could have the calculated column visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> =TEXT(WEEKDAY([Due Date]),"dddd")&" "&TEXT(MONTH([Due Date]),"MMMM")&" "&DAY([Due Date])&" ,"&YEAR([Due Date])